# Accessing Client IP Address (REMOTE_ADDR) in Asp.Net 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

Im trying to get **ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]** in asp.net.

this is my old code (webapi 2) :

```
private Logn GLog(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
{
    Ln Log = new LogInformation();
    Lg.IP = requestContext.HttpContext.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
    Lg.RemoteIP = requestContext.HttpContext.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
    ............................
```

from What I've Learned they changed "**Routing.RequestContext**" to

"**IHttpContextAccessor**"  in vNext version.

how can i achive above result with **IHttpContextAccessor** ?

this gave me error on "**ServerVariables**" part:

```
private Logn GLog(IHttpContextAccessor requestContext)
{
    Ln Log = new LogInformation();
    Lg.IP = requestContext.HttpContext.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use `ConnectionInfo.RemoteIpAddress` instead:

```
private Logn GLog(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
{
    Ln Log = new LogInformation();
    Lg.IP = contextAccessor.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks For answer.Is there any chance to find out "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR" replacement , too ?

Comment: Have you checked `contextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers`? It isn't logically related but I've seen some codes in the past that are using it.

Comment: Does this resolve the issue when the RemoteIpAddress is null in production IIS?